# Trying to reinstall OS X, asking for apple ID "temporarily not available"

Tags: macos

I have a computer (Mac OS X 10.9.x) that became corrupted so I have reformatted the hard drive and am attempting to reinstall the operating system. It asks me to log in with an apple ID so I logged in to one I haven't used in awhile. I get the error message:

> This item is temporarily unavailable. Try again later.

What can I do to get this computer up and running again? I have also tried using a different Apple ID, but when I went to reset my password, I don't receive the password reset email.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mavericks was the operating system, which isn't available in the app store. I was able to boot into internet recovery mode via `command+option+r` and reinstall the original operating system. From there I will be able to upgrade to the latest. Also, apparently the HD corruption happened because we shouldn't have tried to upgrade from Mavericks.